# delete the data from cube SSAS 2008

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssas

I have developed a cube SSAS 2008, in the process of testing we are loading data from datamart to cube using SSIS analysis services processing task.

Problem:

In order to do various tests, we need to clear data in cube for each test. 
How to delete data from the cube, so that cube comes to the origianl schema state.

thanks

prav

Comment: Hey, I have solved the delete the data in cube, as the processStructure uisng the XMLA script generated from the CUBE process task.

Comment: You can also connect to the cube and select "Unprocess" in processing options, if you're not looking for a script/ssis way of doing it.

Comment: Hey prav can you post your own answer and mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using SSIS Analysis services processing task. This will Process dimensions and cube, which will refresh data in cube. You can find a step by step discussion on Benny Austin' Blog [here](https://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/processcube/). Alternatively you can find out an answer [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2994/configuring-the-analysis-services-processing-task-in-sql-server-2012-integration-services/) for Sql Server 2012.